# Clear content with Backspace in Summernote field

Tags: javascript, summernote

The problem is when I clear all content with `Backspace` button causes default

```
<p><br></p>
```

tags to be deleted in `Summernote 0.8.18`

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tinymce-editor').summernote({
      placeholder: 'За допълнителна информация въведете тук.',
      tooltip: false,
      toolbar: [
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['font', ['superscript', 'subscript']],
      ],
      height:150
    });
  });
  </script>
```

[image]

After that no text can be added unless some of the editor button are clicked.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just discover in my `css` that I used :

```
div:empty
{
   display: none;
}
```

After removed it, problem solved.